# Close detail panel and open another on material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am displaying a table in the detail panel of another table using material-table. I want to close or remove  the existing detail panel on clicking another row data expand icon and open the detail panel of that particular row. This is the codesandbox link im working on https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-8zy6z?file=/demo.js:0-2696.
Note: I want to close first and then need to open the other row data detail panel

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with useState

```
const [activePanel, setActivePanel] = React.useState(null)
```

now onClick of row you can do something like this

```
onClick={() => setActivePanel(item._id)}
```

now you know what is active item

```
{activePanel && <>your jsx code goes here</>}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tableRef and change the dataManager detail panel type from multiple to single.

```
import {useRef } from "react";

const tableRef = useRef(0);


<MaterialTable
     tableRef={tableRef}
     detailPanel={(rowData) => {    
              if (tableRef.current.dataManager !== null) {
                tableRef.current.dataManager.detailPanelType = "single";
              }
              return (
               //your Table here
              );
            }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by adding the following prop in options prop of material-table

`detailPanelType: "single",`

e.g:
options:{{
detailPanelType: "single",
}}